# Continuity of straight-line homotopy (for f,g: X to S where S is a convex set)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I read that if $f,g: X\rightarrow C$ are continuous functions from a topological space to a convex set of an Euclidean space, then the function $F: X\times I\rightarrow C$ defined by
$$
F(x,t) = (1-t)f(x) + tg(x)
$$
is a *straight-line* homotopy from $f$ to $g$. May I wonder why is it continuous? I know that I should use the fact that the composition of continuous functions is continuous, and I proved that the function that sends
$$
(x,t)\mapsto ((1-t,t),(f(x),g(x)))
$$
is continuous, but I was stuck there. I was stuck on this example for about two hours so I really appreciate if someone could show me what the composition functions should look like.

Thanks!

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ continuous in the first place?

Comment: @Gibbs Yes, I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of continuous functions is continuous (by composition with the continuous addition function), so if we can show $(t,x)\to tg(x)$ is continuous it should be clear that this is enough. But the scalar product map $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ is continuous and so are its restrictions and corestrictions.

It then suffices to show $(t,x)\to(t,g(x))$ is continuous but that’s really rather clear as it is simply $1\times g$ and the product of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure, by saying that the sum of continuous functions is continuous, do you mean that if $f,g: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, then $f+g: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous? Even though $X$ might not be a subspace of some Euclidean space.

Comment: Yes. This is true by a direct check that basically mimics how you would do it for maps $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. More abstractly, that's because $f+g$ is "really" the composite: $X\overset{\Delta}{\hookrightarrow}X\times X\overset{f\times g}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n\overset{+}{\longrightarrow}\Bbb R^n$ and each term in this composition is continuous. @Coco

Comment: Thanks. What does the triangle mean in the first inclusion map?

Comment: @Coco It's standard notation for the "diagonal" map $x\mapsto(x,x)$. This is always continuous and appears in many contexts, not just topology.

Comment: Thank you! And the second map is the one that sends $(x,y)$ to $(f(x),g(y))$?

Comment: @Coco Yes, and $1\times g$ similarly denotes the map $(t,x)\mapsto(t,g(x))$.